# What is Laravel websocket's url?

Tags: laravel, websocket, localhost

I'm using Laravel Websockets as my websocket server and I was wondering what is its URL? I've set the port to 6001 and the host is `localhost` but when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:6001` or `ws://127.0.0.1:6001`, I get a 404 response. Any idea to get the good URL?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really go to ws port through browser. In that case, you should bootstrap a quick front-end application that initialize the Laravel Echo with configuration to your web socket server.

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  wsHost: window.location.hostname,
  forceTLS: false,
  wsPort: 6001,
  disableStats: true,
  authEndpoint: "http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth",
  key: "123321",
  enabledTransports: ["wss", "ws"],
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer `,
    },
  },
});

 window.Echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind("connected", () => {
   console.log("connected");
});
```

With that setup, you could load your front-end and inspect the console and you should see the connected message.

You can also go network tab in inspect and sort for WS network only, you'll see a messages being sent in real time.

Answer (score 0):

If you open `resources/js/boostrap.js`.

You can actually change the value of the `laravel-echo` host and port.

if you're using socket.io

```js
window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'socket.io',
     host: 'localhost:3001'
});
```

reference:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L23

Comment: im using laravel websockets ,https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction

Comment: i dont know where it is, @Darick

Comment: Set that value in your .env. That will be the port of your websocket

Comment: i changed it to 3001, still there's no socket in ws://127.0.0.1:3001

Comment: Have you tried closing your server and re-running the websocket server?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work, i'm really confused I've tried over 50 different ports directories but i can't find the socket url

Comment: Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...  , but it's not on port 6001 either